# What happened to Cassandra?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Cassandra is the little girl saved from planet P8X-987 after her people were wiped out by Nirti, she was adopted by Dr Janet Fraiser and featured in several episodes.

> However, after the 'Heroes' episodes in which Dr Fraiser dies

I don't remember her ever being mentioned or appearing in the show again - she seemingly disappears from the story line without explanation.

What happened to Cassandra? Is this ever covered in the remaining seasons of Stargate?

Comment: http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Cassandra might help

Comment: Please use >! to mark spoilers. Some of us still haven't watched the whole series.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, she appears in a 1 subsequent episode after "Heroes: Part2" (Src: [SG1 Wikia](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Cassandra)).

> After Fraiser died in 2003 Carter helped her deal with the loss (episode S9E7: "Ex Deus Machina")

She also appeared in a previous episode, but chronologically in the future:

> When SG-1 tried to return to 1999 from the year 1969, they instead ended in the year 2089. There they met an old Cassandra, who sent them back to 1999 through the Stargate (S2E21: "1969").

Answer (score 1):

There was an episode in which SG1 stumbles upon an abandoned lab which had formerly belonged to Nirti.  When the team inadvertently reactivated the lab, Cassandra begins to change and to display telekinetic powers.  As the powers get stronger, Cassandra's physiology begins to change and she becomes dangerous and deathly ill, and the team must race to save her life.

> In another episode, not long after Janet Fraiser, who is acting as a combat medic/field surgeon, dies in a battle on another planet, Cassandra is shown to be having a very difficult time dealing with the loss of Janet, her adoptive mother, and incredible guilt for the terrible way she treated her mother throughout puberty.  Carter helps Cassandra to cope with the loss and vows to take a more active role in Cassandra's life.

Comment: I haven't watched this, but maybe put in spoiler tags?

Answer (score 0):

***SPOILER ALERT***

During "Heroes: Pt 2" (S7E18), just after we find out it was Frasier and not O'Neill that got killed, O'Neill asks Carter is asked how Cassie is doing, to which Carter responds "She's a strong kid."   Later in "Ex Deus Machina" (S9E ), while evading another of Agent Barrett's awkward attempts to woo her, Carter tells him that she took an R&D position so she could spend time with Cassie because she'd been "going through a hard time".  So in response to your question, Cassie is only mentioned but not seen after "Rite Of Passage" (S5E6).  I always thought it was odd that she wasn't at Frasier's memorial service.